# Bad local StackMapTable

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javap

I've generated a simple getter method with ASM in an already existent class.

```
mv = cn.visitMethod(access,                    // public method
                    "get_" + f.name,           // name
                    "()Ljava/lang/String;",    // descriptor
                    null,                      // signature (null means not generic)
                    null);                     // exceptions (array of strings

mv.visitCode();
mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD, cn.name, f.name, f.desc);
mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ARETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
```

Then I generated the class.

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
cn.accept(cw);
```

Now, I can access the class via cw.toByteArray().
The problem is when I try the load the class I get an error because the StackMapTable isn't right (it should be, I'm using ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES ?)

The error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    a.get_c()Ljava/lang/String; @0: aload_0
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[0]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0012 b0
```

After this I added a CheckClassAdapter to see what is wrong.

```
CheckClassAdapter ca = new CheckClassAdapter(cw, false); //Check data flow
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(cw.toByteArray());
ca.verify(cr, new GenericClassLoader(), true, new PrintWriter(new PrintStream(System.out)));
```

The output is the following.

```
org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 0: Expected an object reference, but found .
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.verify(Unknown Source)
    at me.ffy00.ClassGenerator2.generateSkeleton(ClassGenerator2.java:85)
    at me.ffy00.Test.main(Test.java:25)
Caused by: org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Expected an object reference, but found .
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.copyOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicVerifier.copyOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
get_c()Ljava/lang/String;
00000 .  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 ?   :     GETFIELD a.c : Ljava/lang/String;
00002 ?   :     ARETURN
```

If I take a look to my method get_c() I can see it has ? in some Opcodes (maybe because the first Opcode isn't understood?)

```
00000 .  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 ?   :     GETFIELD a.c : Ljava/lang/String;
00002 ?   :     ARETURN
```

I don't really now what that means but the method doesn't look like it's supposed. I compiled a simple Getter class and the method looks like this.

```
00000 Getter  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 Getter  : Getter  :     GETFIELD me/ffy00/Getter.a : Ljava/lang/String;
00002 Getter  : String  :     ARETURN
```

I already tried to set the class version to 50 because the StackMapTable wasn't implemented yet, but it doesn't appear to change anything. I just set the version variable of the ClassNode to 50.
Like this.

```
cn.version = 50;
```

And the class looks like this in javap.

```
public class a
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
```

Also using javap I can get my method, including the stack size and the local number but the method doesn't have a StackMapTable (yes I'm using -v, the StackMapTable shows in other methods).

```
  static java.lang.String get_c();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=0
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #18                 // Field c:Ljava/lang/String;
         4: areturn
```

My variable looks like this.

```
  private static final java.lang.String c;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
```

Can some point me to what I need to do to fix the method. I couldn't find any helpful information about how to fix the StackMapTable with ASM.

Comment: Your comment says that `access` is `public method`, but `javap` thinks your method is default-visibility (aka package) _and static_. Only non-static methods get `this` in arg0.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I totally forgot that. The method body needs to be different for the static getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by dave_thompson_085, the problem is that you accidentally made the method static, but you are still accessing `this`. Or in bytecode terms, you are trying to load an object out of slot 0, but there is nothing in slot 0 at the start of the method.

ASM only generates the stack frames based on the code you give it. It can't magically generate valid stackframes for invalid code.

Comment: Thaks! I forgot that. Can you just explain me why we need to load this for non-static getter methods? I'm still learning bytecode but there isn't a lot of information.

Comment: @FFY00 You're accessing a non-static field, which means you need some object to access the field on. The same is true in Java, it's just that the `this` is implicit.

Comment: In this specific case, ASM doesn’t generate any stack frames at all, as the method doesn’t contain any branches. The first frame, the `VerifyError` refers to, is implied by the method signature. @FFY00 if you look again at the `VerifyError` carefully, you'll notice that the term “StackMapTable” doesn’t appear anywhere in the message.